# What companies provide translation services for LaTeX (XeLaTeX UTF-8) documents?

Tags: xetex, languages

## Question

What are one's possibilities for getting UTF-8 .tex files translated? This is more of a wiki-style question. If anybody says to do a google search, errrr.

### Criteria

- source language: **ANY**
- output language: **ANY**
- types of documents: **robust** (meaning any kind, meaning the most complicated kind, which I suppose is technical)
- custom **embedded variables should be left alone** (making it difficult for translators who just extract the text from the predefined LaTeX code)

I think a consolidated list of services on this site would be very beneficial to this community!

### Software Used

It would also be interesting to mention the software each company uses to handle .tex files, if known. So far I have seen:

- SDL Trados
- Across
- Transit

Comment: Please specify what kind(s) of translation services you're interested in: source language(s), destination language(s), types of documents (novels, technical reports, wedding invitations)?

Comment: source language: ANY, output language: ANY, types of documents: robust (meaning any kind, meaning the most complicated kind, which I suppose is technical)

Comment: I don't see the TeX link here. Translators aren't going to work on your TeX source, they are going to translate your _text_ in some form usable by them.

Comment: @JosephWright Respectfully, I know our translation company (eLinga GmbH) works on the source. (I should hope they don't translate macro names themselves :) They tried extracting the text, but it actually proved to be more confusing than helpful. I just sent them a list of macros NOT to translate. However, since this question has been sitting here without an answer for a year, I am considering deleting it.